# Including imported libraries in jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest

Haven't been able to find how to do this without an IDE (got this far without one).

I have a couple libraries I imported into my code, here are a few examples.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
```

I have the following file structure:

- root dir = RackSerials

  - sub dir *lib* - where all .jar import files
    are included
  - sub dir *tdms* - all my .class files

I tried including all the .jar files in my manifest

```
Main-Class: tdms.rackserials
Class-Path: lib.commons-collections4-4.2.jar lib.commons-compress-1.18.jar lib.json-20180813.jar lib.json-simple-1.1.1.jar lib.poi-4.0.0.jar lib.poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar lib.poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.0.jar lib.xmlbeans-3.0.1.jar
```

However if I move my JAR to another computer (that does not have the required libraries installed) it errors out with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory
```

I found this NOTE in another thread.. so how do I include those other JAR files (the imported libraries) to make my package portable?

> Note: The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the
>   local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible
>   over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR
>   file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those
>   classes. For example, if MyJar.jar contains another JAR file called
>   MyUtils.jar, you cannot use the Class-Path header in MyJar.jar's
>   manifest to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path.

Comment: You can assemble zip file with your own jar and lib directory with all dependencies and ship that zip